# R grepl in dataframe

Tags: r, grepl

I am trying to check whether strings in a column appear in a different column. I tried `grepl`:

```
grepl("b", "d,b,c", fixed = TRUE)
> TRUE
```

which works fine on "standalone" objects, but in a dataframe:

```
 df = data.frame(id = c("a","b"), ids = c("b,c", "d,b,c")) %>%
     mutate(match = grepl(id, .$ids, fixed = TRUE), truematch = c(FALSE, TRUE))

> df
  id   ids match truematch
1  a   b,c FALSE     FALSE
2  b d,b,c FALSE      TRUE
```

it does not result in what I expected, i.e. I am trying to create the column `truematch` but I can only produce `match`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `sapply` over `grepl`,

```
 df %>%  mutate(match = sapply(1:nrow(.),function(x) grepl(.$id[x], .$ids[x])))
```

gives,

```
  id   ids  match
1  a   b,c FALSE
2  b d,b,c  TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `grepl` is not vectorised, we can use `rowwise` to apply it for each row

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(truematch = grepl(id, ids, fixed = TRUE))

#  id    ids   match truematch
#  <fct> <fct> <lgl> <lgl>    
#1 a     b,c   FALSE FALSE    
#2 b     d,b,c FALSE TRUE
```

However, `rowwise` is kind of outdated, we can use `purrr::map2_lgl` with `grepl`

```
df %>% mutate(truematch = purrr::map2_lgl(id, ids, grepl, fixed = TRUE))
```

---

However, for this case a better option is `stringr::str_detect` which is vectorised over string and pattern

```
df %>% mutate(truematch = stringr::str_detect(ids, fixed(id)))
```